# Hide two navigation elements until and unless its scrolled horizontally to 70px of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a **LOGO** on top left and a **search bar** on top right side of the page. I have a **position:fixed navigation bar** below to that LOGO and search bar and it act as fixed once the LOGO part is scrolled down.

Now the problem is when i **scrolled down the logo part**, search bar and one more element should come in to the visible mode in navigation bar.

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fastnto/v97qg/)**

please help me out to do this, have searched a lot but this drained my day.

```
window.onscroll = changePos;function changePos() {
var header = document.getElementById("header");
if (window.pageYOffset > 70) {
    header.style.position = "fixed";
    header.style.top = "0";
} else {
    header.style.position = "";
    header.style.top = "";
}}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @NathanLee yeah now i gave the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fastnto/v97qg/)

Comment: With Jquery like this http://jsfiddle.net/v97qg/8/?

Comment: @Danko hey that is it, thanks a lot. I ill apply that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

- First add a class to hide your elemnts:

  ```
   <li class="hiden"> <a href="#">Logo</a></li>
   <li class="hiden"> <a href="#">Search</a></li>

   .wrapper #nav li.hiden {
      display:none;
   }
  ```
- Then add to your function `show()` and `hide()` Jquery methods for that class:

  ```
  function changePos() {
    var header = $('#header'),
    sT = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (sT > 70) {
      header.css({'position':'fixed','top':'0'});
      $('.hiden').show();
    } else {
      header.css({'position':'relative','top':' '});
      $('.hiden').hide();
    }
  ```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/v97qg/8/

Comment: @Fastnto are you adding the class for both elements? ... If you can reproduce the issue in a fiddle

Comment: @Fastnto you are wrong  adding a class .. you have `class="nav_search" class="hiden"` the duplicate isn't valid it must be `class="nav_search hiden"` with a whitespace between class http://jsfiddle.net/v97qg/13/

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the Logo and Search into the header and let them be positioned absolute/relative as long as the header isn't fixed. Which means I wouldn't fix it directly with JS but give the header a CSS class which has the fixed property.

I wrote completely new stuff because I restructured the HTML a little bit, because I think it's not necessary to write redundant HTML. A jsfiddle is at the end of the post.

HTML:

```
<div id="top-space"></div>
<div id="navigation">
    <span id="logo">Logo</span>
    <span id="search">Search</span>

    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>

<div id="content">...</div>
```

JS is just like your function but with a className property instead:

```
window.onscroll = changePos;

function changePos () {
    var header = document.getElementById("navigation");

    if (window.pageYOffset > 70) {
        header.className = 'fixed';
    } else {
        header.className = '';
    }
}
```

And CSS stuff:

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

#top-space {
    height: 70px;
}
#navigation {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;

    background: black;
}

#navigation.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}

#navigation a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
}
#search {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

#domain-name, #search {
    margin-top: -70px;
}

#navigation.fixed #domain-name,
#navigation.fixed #search {
    position: static;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Or just look it up in the jsfiddle.

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/cugN7/3/